# Animated background for button

Tags: java, android

How to make animated background for button in Android Studio

1. Hello guys, I am an java android application developer.  In my project, I want to use a button with an animated background. What does it mean? The button class has a method .setBackgroundResource(int res_id), where do we pass R.drawable.some_res. I have video(R.raw.some_video). Can I use this video as a background for a button, and so that when it ends, it starts playing again. And another question is whether this background will consume a lot of phone resources.

Answer (score 0):

To create an animated background for a button in Android Studio, you can use an animation drawable.

1. Create a new XML file in the res/drawable folder and give it a descriptive name, such as "button_background.xml".
2. In the XML file, add the following code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_1" android:duration="50"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/frame_2" android:duration="50"/>
    <!-- Add additional frames as needed -->
</animation-list>
```

3. Replace "frame_1" and "frame_2" with the names of the drawables you want to use for each frame of the animation.
4. In your button's Java code, set the background of the button using the following code:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_background);
```

Note that the "android:oneshot" attribute is set to "false", which means that the animation will repeat indefinitely. If you want the animation to play only once, set this attribute to "true".

Keep in mind that using animations as background resources can consume more system resources than using static images, so be mindful of the size and length of the animation.